# How can I use pico or festival with pyttsx3?

Tags: python-3.x, pyttsx3, festival

I want to use pico or festival as engine in pyttsx3 (on an Ubuntu machine), but when I write something like
'''engine = pyttsx3.init('pico')'''
it tells me that there is no module named pyttsx3.drivers.pico. However I have installed both:

ii  libttspico-data                               1.0+git20130326-12                         all          Small Footprint TTS (lingware)
ii  libttspico-dev:amd64                          1.0+git20130326-12                         amd64        Small Footprint TTS (development files)
ii  libttspico-utils                              1.0+git20130326-12                         amd64        Small Footprint TTS (binaries)
ii  libttspico0:amd64                             1.0+git20130326-12                         amd64        Small Footprint TTS (library)

ii  festival                                      1:2.5.0-8                                  amd64        General multi-lingual speech synthesis system
ii  festival-dev                                  1:2.5.0-8                                  amd64        Development kit for the Festival speech synthesis system
ii  festvox-kallpc16k

What should I do?